# There is an Error in tkinter python GUI. How to fix it?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, Menu, Button


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Notebook')
window.geometry('320x320')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)
notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280).pack(fill='both', expand=True)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280).pack(fill='both', expand=True)

notebook.add(frame1, text='General Profile Sett')
notebook.add(frame2, text='My profile')

window.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/PycharmProjects/Python_Project_1/GUI.py", line 55, in <module>
    notebook.add(frame1, text='General Profile Sett')
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 844, in add
    self.tk.call(self._w, "add", child, *(_format_optdict(kw)))
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!notebook add window ?-option value ...?"
```

Comment: Did you notice that `frame1` and `frame2` are `None`? They are result of `pack(...)` not `ttk.Frame(...)`.  Actually you don't need to call `.pack(...)` on the frames at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the issue that has been asked many times in StackOverflow:

```py
frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280).pack(fill='both', expand=True)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280).pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

`frame1` and `frame2` are `None` because they are results of `pack(...)` instead of `ttk.Frame(...)`.

Actually, you don't need to call `pack(...)` at all since they are added into the notebook by `notebook.add(...)`.

```py
frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)

notebook.add(frame1, text='General Profile Sett')
notebook.add(frame2, text='My profile')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .pack() in 13 and 14th line since you already mentioned that .add() on below...